# how to set max_parallel_workers_per_gather permanently?

Tags: postgresql

I am experiencing problems with parallelism due to `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`

I have set the following parameters in `postgresql.conf`:

```
max_worker_processes = 64
max_parallel_workers = 32
max_parallel_workers_per_gather =32
```

though, `SHOW max_parallel_workers_per_gather;` returns 0, unless I set the parameter within current session.

`EXPLAIN` returns `Workers Planned` only if I set `SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather to 32;` within the explained query.

Though, I can not set the parameter with every query, since I work through `python` `sqlalchemy`

`postgres db` works within `docker` container

How to set the `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` permanently?

Comment: Did you reload the configuration after changing `postgresql.conf`

Comment: And, after reloading, did you check the log file if it worked?

Comment: And check the "source" column from "pg_setttings"

Comment: I did restarted the docker container. Also the other parameters set have changed to the right.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe, how to check the log file?

Comment: @jjanes the "source" column from "pg_setttings" for max_parallel_workers_per_gather is 0, so it has not changed

Comment: How to check the log file: Open it with a text editor or a pager and read.

Comment: The `source` column should contain something like `configuration file`, `session` or `environment variable`, certainly not the value `0`

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name, sorry, the value of the `source` column is  `user`

Comment: OK, so that will override postgresql.conf, and was done by something like `alter user foobar set max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0;`

Comment: @jjanes, how that can happen? Definitely, the is no such thing in my code.

Comment: @ jjanes, `alter user postgres set max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 32;` seem to have helped

Comment: This indicates that your application is using the `postgres` user to connect to the database. That is s a really bad idea. You shouldn't be using the superuser from within your application- that is a **huge** security risk!